# Помогите перенести данные со второго экрана на первый в kivy проекте

Tags: python, kivy

Приложение на kivy для мобильного телефона, которое делает подсчёт вводимых данных на главном экране на коэффициент на втором экране соответственно. и вывод результата на главный экран в лейблы. Я пытался сделать это, но не могу разобраться.

````
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 320)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 640)


class SecondWindow(Screen):
   
    
    my_variable = ObjectProperty()
    my_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    def submit_text_input(self):
        self.my_variable = float(self.my_text_input.text)*3
        print(self.my_variable)
        self.my_variable = ObjectProperty()
        

      
        
class MainWindow(Screen):
    
    
    my_variable1 = ObjectProperty(3) 
    
    
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return kv
    
    def close_app(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop()

    def save_variable(self, value):
        self.my_variable = value
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()```

второй файл

```#:kivy 2.2.1

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    
    BoxLayout:
        
        
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding: 3
        Button:
            text: "Настройки"
            size_hint:(0.3, 0.1)
            pos_hint:{'x': 0.65, 'y': 1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        GridLayout:
            rows:10
            spacin:13
            paddin:2
            Label:
                
                text: 'По трассе'
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.1  
                font_size: 20 
                pos_hint:{'x': 1, 'top': 1}

            TextInput:
                id: trassa_zn
                text:'sa'
                size_hint_y:0.3
                padding:13
                
            
            Label:
                text: 'По городу'
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.1  
                font_size: 20 
                pos_hint:{'x': 1, 'top': 1}

           
            TextInput:
                id: my_text_input
                text: ''
                multiline:False
                size_hint_y:0.3
                padding:13
           

            Label:
                text: 'По пересеченке'
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.1  
                font_size: 20 
                pos_hint:{'x': 1, 'top': 1}

            TextInput:
                text:''
                multiline:False
                size_hint_y:0.3
                padding:13

            Button:
                text:'Рассчитать'
                size_hint:(0.3, 0.5)
                on_press:
                    print(trassa_zn.text) 
                    trassa_zn.text = str(root.my_variable1)
                    print(trassa_zn.text)
                    
                
      
            Button:
                text:'Выход'
                size_hint:(0.3, 0.5)
                on_release: app.close_app()
                
        


        
        



<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    my_text_input: my_text_input_id
    my_variable: my_text_input2
    BoxLayout:
        
        
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding: 3
        
            
        GridLayout:
            rows:10
            spacin:13
            paddin:2
            Label:
                text: 'Расход трасса'
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.1  
                font_size: 20 
                pos_hint:{'x': 1, 'top': 1}

            TextInput:
                id: trassa
                text:'8.21'
                size_hint_y:0.3
                padding:13

            
            Label:
                text: 'Расход город'
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.1  
                font_size: 20 
                pos_hint:{'x': 1, 'top': 1}

           
            TextInput:
                id: my_text_input2
                text:'8.21'
                multiline:False
                size_hint_y:0.3
                padding:13
                
           

            Label:
                text: 'Расход пересеченка'
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.1  
                font_size: 20 
                pos_hint:{'x': 1, 'top': 1}

            TextInput:
                id: my_text_input_id
                text:'9.35'
                multiline:False
                size_hint_y:0.3
                padding:13

        Button:
            text: "Сохранить"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                root.submit_text_input()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй передавать переменные черeз APP.
App.glob_values = self.my_variable

Comment: пожалуйста опиши подробнее, свою мысль